# Timer to load random frame not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I have three frames with "800", "450", and "635"

I updated the codes and its just jumps to frame to frame every 1 seconds now. Thats not what I need. I need the counter to reach to 0 and it jumps to ONE frame and stops right there. Thats it.

[**UPDATED 2**] See banner - http://magnixsolutions.com/clients/OT/9995MB-Scoreboard-April-160x600.swf

AS3 -

```
var fromFrame:int = 1;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, nCount);
var frameNum:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * mcYourScore.totalFrames)

timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

function getRandomFromRange(minValue:Number, maxValue:Number):int {
return Math.round(minValue + Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue));
}

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
//Display countdown
timer_txt.text = String(myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount);
//if End of countdown, start from 2 frame
fromFrame = (myTimer.repeatCount == myTimer.currentCount) ? 2 : 1;
mcYourScore.gotoAndStop(getRandomFromRange(fromFrame, mcYourScore.totalFrames)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.round(Math.random()) doesn't have any sense, it will return only 0 or 1 values.

```
var frameNum:int = Math.round(1 + Math.random() * (mcYourScore.totalFrames-1));
```

If you want to visit random frame on every tick, this construction should help you:

```
var seconds:int;

function getRandomFromRange(minValue:Number, maxValue:Number):int {
    return Math.round(minValue + Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue));
}

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //Display countdown
    seconds = myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount;
    timer_txt.text = seconds.toString();
    //if End of countdown, start from 2 frame
     mcYourScore.gotoAndStop(getRandomFromRange(((seconds == 0) ? 2 : 1), mcYourScore.totalFrames));
}
```

If you want to visit random frame only at the end of countdown, you could use `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` event handler, or change `countdown` logic:

```
function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //Display countdown
    timer_txt.text = String(myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount);
    //if End of countdown, pick random frame, from 2 frame
    if(myTimer.repeatCount == myTimer.currentCount){
        mcYourScore.gotoAndStop(getRandomFromRange(2, mcYourScore.totalFrames));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or less confusingly... `Math.ceil( Math.random() * mcYourScore.totalFrames )`

Comment: Yes, It's also possible approach, if to omit statement from the documentation that `random` can return zero value.

Comment: 0 and one will go to the same frame

Comment: Hey, Bennett & Nic - Thank you very much and your codes works. I have updated the codes and please see the link to the banner. Right now. its jumping to the next frame to frame randomly. I need it to stop on ONE frame after the countdown reaches to 0 and thats it.

Comment: Also the "?" is on frame 1, and rest of the numbers are on frame 2, 3, and 4. So when the countdown reaches to 0 it jumps (AND STOPS) to any one of the frames randomly right there.

Comment: It will stops automatically, because of repeatcount, I have updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just uploaded the banner - see link. It jumps to frame to frame every 1 second now. It need to stop at one of the frames (2, 3, or 4) and stays there after the countdown reaches to 0. The 0 stays there.

Comment: As I can see animation is stopped at random frame.

Comment: Ok, for example at first it displays "?" until the countdown reaches to 0 THEN it jumps to ONE of the frames, say frame 2 "640" and it stops right there. It doesnt change or animate. Its real straight-forward and simple. Right now, when the countdown reaches to 8 it jumps to one of the frames and then it jump the next frame again.

Comment: PERFECT! It works now. Not only that you're awesome, but patience! Thanks man! http://magnixsolutions.com/clients/OT/9995MB-Scoreboard-April-160x600.swf